# Replace a string that contains (0-100) then words

Tags: r, regex

I'm working with some play-by-play data for college football, and a handful of the plays come in a different syntax then the rest. To work around this, I need to make a substitution. For example, I need to turn the following string:

```
"Justin Thomas 13 Yd Run (Jim Delaney Kick)"
```

to:

```
"Justin Thomas run (Jim Delaney Kick)"
```

I'm a little new to using all the ?regex content, and can't quite figure out how to nail this down as the number preceding "Yd Run" could be anything from 0 to 100.

I've tried some different combinations, typically looking something like this:

```
gsub("[0-100]\\sYd Run","run ", "Justin Thomas 13 Yd Run (Jim Delaney Kick)")
```

But I just keep getting the same string back. And since I am not completely understanding of the ?regex, the answers I've seen to similar questions have not been helpful. I'm trying to pattern match, but some things don't seem to carry over, or I'm not fully understanding what each character means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
gsub("[0-9]+ Yd Run","run","Justin Thomas 13 Yd Run (Jim Delaney Kick)")
# [1] "Justin Thomas run (Jim Delaney Kick)"
```

You have to capture digit from 0 to 9 one or more times (`+`)

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `stringr`

```
library(stringr)

string <- "Justin Thomas 13 Yd Run (Jim Delaney Kick)"

str_replace_all(string, " [:digit:]+ [:alpha:]+", "")

# [1] "Justin Thomas Run (Jim Delaney Kick)"
```